# Laravel 7 - Help to Add / Update

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 7, I have a table in my database called

- cells

which has the following fields id, name, created_at, updated_at. However, when a new registration is made, I call the procedure, similar

```
$req->only('name')
```

supposing that I wanted to add which was the user that made such insertion (store), what is the best way to do this in laravel? add a column called user_id and have the value
of `auth()->user()` and include it inside my data object that is sent in the procedure

```
$user = auth()->user();
```

add $ user to the data set, which will be used when calling create?

```
$model->create($data)
```

or is there some other way that laravel already has that can help during record addition and record editing?

Comment: here is the tutorial that shows you many example of saving a model https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-QapNzUE4V0&ab_channel=TraversyMedia

Comment: you can use eloquent events  https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#events

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of using `auth()->user()` should work. Like this, for example:

```
$cell = new Cell();
$cell->name = $request->input('name');
$cell->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
$cell->save();
```

Comment: Is that any better than `Auth::id()`?

Comment: It's basically the same thing. `auth()` users a Helper, `Auth::` a Facade.

The Laravel documentation states: _There is absolutely no practical difference between facades and helper functions_